# Static Dispatch with Final performance comparison

Tags: ios, swift

According to the article by Apple - [Increasing Performance by Reducing Dynamic Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=27), it suggests that dynamic dispatch is not good performance wise

> dynamic dispatch, increases language expressivity at the cost of a
> constant amount of runtime overhead for each indirect usage. In
> performance sensitive code such overhead is often undesirable

Also,

> three ways to improve performance by eliminating such dynamism: final,
> private, and Whole Module Optimization.

From what I understood, it said that when we use `final` keyword, it ensures the compiler that class will never be subclassed and thus increases performance (as without that, there cannot be dynamic dispatch).

So to sum it up, `final` will increase the performance for that class.

So, I performed a basic test to make sure of it :

```
import Foundation

func calculateTimeElapsed(label: String, codeToRun: () -> Void ) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    codeToRun()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(label): \(timeElapsed) sec")
}

class Foo {
    var number: Int = 1
    
    func incrementNumber() {
        number += 1
    }
}

final class Bar {
    var number: Int = 1
    
    func incrementNumber() {
        number += 1
    }
}

let fooObject = Foo()

calculateTimeElapsed(label: "Static Dispatch for Foo") {
    for _ in 0...100000 {
        fooObject.incrementNumber()
    }
}

let barObject = Bar()

calculateTimeElapsed(label: "Static Dispatch for Bar") {
    for _ in 0...100000 {
        barObject.incrementNumber()
    }
}

/// 100000
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Foo: 7.20068895816803 sec
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Bar: 7.22502601146698 sec

/// 200000
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Foo: 13.975957989692688 sec
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Bar: 14.329360961914062 sec

/// 500000
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Foo: 36.355777978897095 sec
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Bar: 36.50222206115723 sec

/// 700000
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Foo: 51.68453896045685 sec
//Time elapsed for Static Dispatch for Bar: 51.46391808986664 sec 
//
```

- Two classes , one final(Bar) and one not (Foo)
- Performed some operations over certain input on objects of both the classes
- Measured the time required for executing both the operations

However, to my surprise, the class that is **not final** takes less time in 3/4 cases. It can be that *when the number of iterations increases*, the result may go into the favor of `final` class, but i need to be sure that this concept is correct to measure.

I know my example might be wrong, but if it is, then can anyone please tell me some other example with which the fact that *`final` increases the performance* is correct

Comment: Maybe your way of testing performance isn't correct. You are looping through barObject later than fooObject, maybe the CPU has cached data or something. Do you run this code in release or debug mode?

Comment: @J.Doe I am not so sure how to change the mode while I'm running it inside playground. But like you suggested, when i moved the call of barObject **before** fooObject, the odds have reduced from 75-25 to 50-50 now. How would you suggest i run this code, like in a simulator or something? or how would you have approached this problem and change the example code?

Comment: I am not a performance tester (but I want to learn :)). I am not sure how to correctly perfomance test this kind of things... Maybe you can run the test in a measure block (available in Xcode XCTestCase) a million times each, independently from each other (without one running right after the other). But again: not sure if this is a good way, just guessing.

Comment: Sounds a good approach to me. I'll learn about it more . Thanks @J.Doe

Comment: Also note than when building in release mode and testing it (you should performance test in release mode) the compiler may notice that the method isn't overridden and infer final automatically. So your test case will be screwed up. I think you should actually override that method.

Comment: @J.Doe Yeah that's what i was afraid might happen, _infer final automatically_ (and idk maybe is happening right now). I subclassed `Foo` and then ran . Now most of the cases are in favor of `final` class but not all. I'll look more into it